# OO like behaviour in CSS: inheritance possible?

Tags: css, inheritance

I have a simple border style say:

```
.border 
{
   /*content*/
}
```

I want several other classes to inherit this border style. Can this be done in CSS only?
Or do I need to specify it in HTML also?

I want:

```
.actionArea : .border
{ 
     /*content */
}
```

Or can this only be done in HTML like:

```
<div class="actionArea border"/>
```

It would be very annoying if the latter is only possible.

**Update**
This works good enough, but still is a bit ugly:

```
.actionArea, .otherArea, .anotherArea
{
    /*border specification */     
}

.actionArea
{
    /*area specification/*
}

.otherArea
{
    /*area specification/*
}

(..)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a CSS framework such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) for such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [sass](http://sass-lang.com) . Probably it is the nesting feature you want to use http://sass-lang.com/#nesting

```
table.hl {
  margin: 2em 0;
  td.ln {
    text-align: right;
  }
}

li {
  font: {
    family: serif;
    weight: bold;
    size: 1.2em;
  }
}
```

Or as Oded said you can use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) . LESS is having some interesting feature one of them is [mixins](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins) . This is not exactly inheritance but it gives you has-a relationship in css

Example copied from LESS

```
.bordered {
  border-top: dotted 1px black;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}

#menu a {
  color: #111;
  .bordered;
}
.post a {
  color: red;
  .bordered;
}
```